# How does DateTime.TryParse know the date format?

Tags: c#, .net, date, parsing, datetime

Here is a scenario.

- You have a string that represents a date i.e. "Jan 25 2016 10:10 AM".
- You want to know whether it represents a date in a specific culture.
- You want to know what dateTime pattern satisfies this date string.

Example:

- Date string is "Jan 25 2016 10:10 AM"
- Culture is en-US
- The POSSIBLE format for it could be "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm tt"

Implementation:

- To get the list of all dateTime patterns you can get a `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()`
- Then try the overloaded version of `DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, pattern, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultingDate)` for each of the patterns above and see whether it can parse a date.
- That should give you the needed dateTime pattern.

**HOWEVER** if we iterate all those patterns it will not find any matches!

This is even more weird if you try and use a `DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultingDate)` and it **DOES** parse the correct date!

So the question is how come the `DateTime.TryParse` knows the pattern of a date string when this info is not a part of `CultureInfo` and how to get to this info in a culture?

Thanks!

Comment: here's the code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,f75289affb7e0ce3

Comment: hmm..the problem is the pattern you use in TryParseExact. You should try ALL the possible patterns

Comment: And what you are trying i think is not possible. Think of this date: `01/02/2016`. It could be `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`. How to know which one without knowing the culture???

Comment: Interesting... **There is no `MMM dd yyyy` format for en-us.**

Comment: @xanatos really???

Comment: @Pikoh Try yourself: `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us").DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns().Where(x => x.StartsWith("MMM")).ToArray()` They all start with `MMMM`

Comment: @Pikoh, that is the thing with dates like 1/1/2016 that can satisfy both patterns

Comment: @Pikoh, yes it is not there, otherwise i wouldn't post a question :)

Comment: `DateTimeFormatInfo.AddMonthNames` is a private method that adds together short month names and full month names. The Token hashset generated is used by the `Parse`/`TryParse`. The `ParseExact`/`TryParseExact` don't use it, but use the `DateTimeParse.MatchAbbreviatedMonthName`/`DateTimeParse.MatchMonthName`

Comment: Much research would be needed to show it is what happens (I've jumped around with Ilspy to find it, but writing it would be long), but I'm 75% sure of this. How can you solve it? Not sure there is a good solution. Probably easier to clone a culture and modify the list of date patterns from there. Then you can `DateTime.TryParse`

Comment: Mmmh... I see it is even a little more complex. It isn't only a `MMM == MMMM`... The en-us patterns with `MMMM` require a `,` after the `dd`

Comment: Don't forget the Locale Builder tool :)  Then en-US could have whatever patterns you want!  And some locales allow interesting formats as alternates, like yyyy/MM/dd - because it's kinda unambiguous by itself, but what do you do if its the last pattern in the list?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with xanatos, there is no *perfect* solution for that and you *can't* assume that *every* format `GetAllDateTimePatterns` returns can be perfectly parsable with `Parse` or `TryParse` methods.

From [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> You can use the custom format strings in the array returned by the
>   `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method in formatting operations. However, if
>   you do, the string representation of a date and time value returned in
>   that formatting operation **cannot always be parsed successfully by the
>   `Parse` and `TryParse` methods. Therefore, you cannot assume that** the
>   custom format strings returned by the `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method
>   can be used to round-trip date and time values.

If you see [`Remarks` section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1) on the page, there are only 42 formats that can be parsed by `TryParse` method in 96 formats that `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method returns for `it-IT` culture for example.7

Tarek Mahmoud Sayed responded as;

> Parse/TryParse are implemented as finite state machine so it doesn’t
>   really use the date patterns in parsing. It just split the parsed
>   string into tokens and try to find if the token match specific part of
>   the date (like Month, day, day of week…etc.). in the other hand
>   ParseExact/TryParseExact will just parse the string according to the
>   passed format pattern.

Comment: I send an email to .NET Team about this situation and see what is the best way (or is there _any_) to get those formats. I will update my answer when they return me.

Answer (score 2):

In short, Parsing is really hard because there are a lot of things that can trip it up.  And someone in some government could suddenly decide that country X should use D/M/Y instead of M/D/Y, or could have someone entering data used to the other format.

I talk a little about this on a blog post (toward the bottom-ish) https://web.archive.org/web/20190110065542/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/04/05/culture-data-shouldnt-be-considered-stable-except-for-invariant/

DateTime.Parse attempts to guess what the input might be based on the pattern(s) and separators it sees in the specified culture.  Unfortunately, some cultures are REALLY hard to guess at.  For example, . has been used for time formats in some locales, so is 1.1.1 12.12.12 the 12th day of December 2012?  Or the 1st day of January 2001?

ParseExact (as the other answers suggest) is more reliable as you can tell it exactly what you're looking for - even better, you can also tell the user exactly what to enter.  (Hopefully this is human input).  Unfortunately it requires the user to follow the template.

This is also why most date controls you encounter, especially on the web, have separate fields for month, day & year.

For machine readable formats its best to spit it out in some standard format and read it back in with that exact same format.  We've had customers send data from one country to another using the CurrentCulture and wonder why their vendor can't read it ;-)